# Pyspark pivot table and create new columns based on values of another column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create new versions of existing columns based on the values of another column. Eg. in the input I create new columns for 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' for each value 'var' split can take.

**Input:**

| time | student | split | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | Student1 | A | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| t1 | Student1 | B | 2 | 5 | 6 |
| t1 | Student1 | C | 3 | 1 | 9 |
| t2 | Student1 | A | 5 | 3 | 7 |
| t2 | Student1 | B | 9 | 6 | 3 |
| t2 | Student1 | C | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| t1 | Student2 | A | 1 | 2 | 8 |
| t1 | Student2 | C | 7 | 4 | 0 |

**Output:**

| time | student | splitA_var1 | splitA_var2 | splitA_var1 | splitB_var1 | splitB_var2 | splitB_var3 | splitC_var1 | splitC_var2 | splitC_var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | Student1 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 9 |
| t2 | Student1 | 5 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| t1 | Student2 | 1 | 2 | 8 |  |  |  | 7 | 4 | 0 |

[Image of output here if table not formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZeQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an easy `pivot` with multiple aggregations (within `agg()`).

see example below

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('pivot_col', func.concat(func.lit('split'), 'split')). \
    groupBy('time', 'student'). \
    pivot('pivot_col'). \
    agg(func.first('var1').alias('var1'), 
        func.first('var2').alias('var2'), 
        func.first('var3').alias('var3')
        ). \
    show()

# +----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# |time| student|splitA_var1|splitA_var2|splitA_var3|splitB_var1|splitB_var2|splitB_var3|splitC_var1|splitC_var2|splitC_var3|
# +----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# |  t1|Student2|          1|          2|          8|       null|       null|       null|          7|          4|          0|
# |  t2|Student1|          5|          3|          7|          9|          6|          3|          3|          5|          3|
# |  t1|Student1|          1|          3|          7|          2|          5|          6|          3|          1|          9|
# +----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

spark will create new columns with the following nomenclature - *<pivot column value>_<aggregation alias>*